# What are the neo4j naming conventions?

Tags: neo4j

I'm curious about naming conventions in neo4j.

I noticed in their examples that relationship names where capitalized, e.g.

```
left-[r:KNOWS]->right
```

Is that the convention?  Is neo4j case sensitive in relationship names?  Are there other naming conventions around index names and property names?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the convention. I personally use lower case relationship types, and yes, it is case-sensitive. With underscores.

Usually, people use underscores for index names as well, and they're usually lower case, and also case-sensitive.

Also, something to remember: if you don't specify direction while creating, the default is left<--right. Not intuitive for me, but now I just specify direction always.

For the properties, I think most people use JSON style conventions: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Key_Names_in_JSON_Maps

I've also seen underscores for properties, so I guess it goes either way. Just be consistent!

Comment: If you want spaces, you can. You need to enclose the relationship type in backticks though. The syntax is often used in MySQL for object names with spaces.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the convention for relationship names is to have them ALL_UPPERCASE. All names in Neo4j are case-sensitive (labels, relationships, properties, ...)

Keep in mind that this is a convention, not a requirement. **The most important part in any project is consistency. *Use a coding style and stick to it throughout!***

Neo4j naming convention:

- Labels: UpperCamelCase (a.k.a. PascalCase)
- Relationships: CAPITALIZED_WITH_UNDERSCORE
- Property key names: lowerCamelCase or snake_case

Cypher examples:

```
CREATE (:Person {name:"Anne"})-[:MANAGES {start_date:20121112}]->(:WorkGroup {name:"Dev"});
```

Alternatively:

```
CREATE (:Person {name:"Anne"})-[:MANAGES {startDate:20121112}]->(:WorkGroup {name:"Dev"});
```

References:

- [The Neo4j Developer Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/#_label_names)
- [The O'Reilly Graph Databases - Neo4j Graph Database](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/)

Answer (score 0):

Could be easier to bring everything to upper  case or lower case using **LOWER()** and **UPPER()** string functions

**1- Let's suppose I have a node with a property name = 'name' in lower case, to find it you need to match againt the exact string**

```
Query:
CYPHER 2.0
START n=node(*)
WHERE n.name= "name"
RETURN id(n)

id(n)
5

Query took 3 ms and returned 1 rows.
```

otherwise you will not find it :

```
Query:
CYPHER 2.0
START n=node(*)
WHERE n.name= "Name"
RETURN id(n)


Query took 4 ms and returned no rows.
```

But, we can match it using string function LOWER():

```
CYPHER 2.0
START n=node(*)
WHERE n.name= LOWER("Name")
RETURN id(n)

id(n)
5

Query took 4 ms and returned 1 rows.
```

**2- With node property entered with arbitrary string case ex: "NaMe", to match against :**

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE LOWER(n.name)= "name"
RETURN id(n)

id(n)
8

Query took 5 ms and returned 1 rows.
```